# SQL query within SQL query on sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, Employees and EmployeeVacations. I am trying to do a SQL query to get the sum of how much vacation time each employee has taken and their current balance as of today. Here is my current SQL query:

```
SELECT
    e.PIN,
    e.FirstName,
    e.LastName,
    e.Uniform,
    e.AL_Cap,
    ev.Value AS '10/1 Balance',
    (SELECT
        SUM(value)
    FROM EmployeeVacations
    WHERE CreationDate >= '2016-10-01'
    AND Vacation_Type = 'Taken'
    AND Vacation_Kind = 'AL'
    AND EmployeeId = 13)
    AS Taken
FROM    employees e,
        EmployeeVacations ev
WHERE e.Id = ev.EmployeeId
AND ev.IsHistory = 0
AND ev.Vacation_Type = 'Forward'
AND ev.Vacation_Kind = 'AL'
AND EmployeeId = 13
ORDER BY e.LastName, e.FirstName
```

This works if I pick a single employee. If I remove the "where EmployeeId = 13", I get a list of all the employees with the sum of everyone's total vacation in every row (like 1,300 hours). How do I break it down so it only shows the Taken for each employee specifically?

Comment: Depending on what version of sql server you are using this could likely be handled using a windowed function.

Comment: You should use explicit joins--it's far more legible.

Comment: You are showing a list of an employee's foreward records, each along with the employee's taken sum. Is this desired? Or do you rather want the employee's foreward sum, too, i.e. only one result row per employee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing that you also might want the sum rather than the single forward records... Here is a query that aggregates `EmployeeVacations` per `EmployeeId`:

```
select
  e.pin,
  e.firstname,
  e.lastname,
  e.uniform,
  e.al_cap,
  ev.forward_sum as "10/1 balance",
  ev.taken_sum as taken
from employee e
left join
(
  select     
    employeeid,
    sum(case when vacation_type = 'Forward' 
             and ishistory = 0 then value else 0 end) as forward_sum,
    sum(case when vacation_type = 'Taken' 
             and creationdate >= '20161001' then value else 0 end) as taken_sum,
  from employeevacations
  where vacation_kind = 'AL'
  group by employeeid
) ev on ev.employeeid = e.employeeid
order by e.lastname, e.firstname;
```

Please ...

- use explicit joins instead of the pre-1992 comma-separated joins for readability and for being less prone to errors.
- use double quotes for alias names; single quotes are for string literals.
- use 'yyyymmdd' for dates; it is the supported date literal format in SQL Server.

Comment: I like this solution, it looks cleaner and makes more sense.

Comment: How do I subtract ev.taken_sum from ev.forward_sum into a new column? I tried

sum(ev.forward_sum - ev.taken_sum) as "10/24 Balance"

but it's giving me a group by error.  Thanks!

Comment: How to subtract `ev.taken_sum` from `ev.forward_sum`? Well, with a minus sign of course: `ev.forward_sum - ev.taken_sum`. Your additional `sum` simply makes no sense.

Comment: That worked, Thanks! I guess I was trying to over-think it. I always thought any calculation in SQL needed to use SUM like in an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

You need a corelated query, where the subquery uses a value from the "parent" query.

```
SELECT e.PIN ...
    (select SUM(value) .... WHERE EmployeeID = e.id) as taken
                                               ^^^^^
```

Note that these can be very inefficient, since the inner query has to be executed once for every row of the parent query. IN a lot of cases, you may be better off re-writing as a conventional `JOIN` query with appropriate grouping.

Comment: Emphasis on Mac's last paragraph. 99% chance this can be written more efficiently.

Comment: That would be a very bad optimizer, if it came out with a completely different execution plan for semantically the same query.

Comment: Since I'm not a SQL expert using Joins, Marc's suggestion worked. Thanks, Marc!